# Merging files via transformer

Tags: dart

Say I'm creating a site.

Currently I need to run a task which will compile template files and merge them into a .js file.

So I'm reading [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/) guide about transformers and trying to create one.

But seems that I can only handle assets in transformer individually, via `transform.primaryInput.id`.

So, I'm wondering, how can I merge some assets into one file via a transformer?

Comment: This discussion https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/EXd93ULV80Y has some insightful comments about the limitations of transformers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question.

What I need is an `aggregate transformer`.

This article should solve the problem: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/aggregate.html